# Lower floats and ints in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I add a conditional in my function? My problem is some values of my dict are floats and ints.

```
def lower_dict(d):
    new_dict = dict((k.lower(), v.lower()) for k, v in d.items())
    return new_dict
```

Comment: 1. check for `.lower()` via `hasattr('', 'lower')` or `isinstance('', str)` and 2. incorporate this with if-else logic

Comment: `new_dict = dict((k.lower(), v.lower()) for k, v in d.items() if hasattr(v, 'lower') == False)` something like this?

Comment: more like `dict((k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k, v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v) for k, v in d.items())`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use a dict-comprehension to clean up that line, and I would create a helper function and lower in a try/except:

```
def try_lower(x):
    try:
        return x.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        return x

def lower_dict(d):
    return {try_lower(k): try_lower(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Alternatively use `hasattr` for the helper function.